# Replace radio buttons with select element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need dynamic script which detects radio button by name and replace it with select element.

These radio buttons can be anywhere in the DOM. I need to distinguish using names and replace it with relevant select-box.

**For example input** :

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Car Type
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="Type"> Old
        <input type="radio" name="Type"> New
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Required output** :

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Car Type
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="Type">
            <option value="Old">Old</option>
            <option value="New">New</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I tried something, but no success (My Script)

```
//removing all radio
  var radios = document.getElementsByName(name);
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    radios[i].parentNode.removeChild(radios[i]);
  }
  //replaceing wih select
  var selectList = document.createElement("select");
  selectList.name = name;
  radios[0].parentNode.appendChild(selectList);
  //Create and append the options
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = data[i];
    option.text = data[i];
    selectList.appendChild(option);
  }
```

[Plunker full example](https://plnkr.co/edit/8LUh4NYFtXWa3SBRhN37?p=preview)

Comment: So what is the problem? you code works.

Comment: @dfsq ya it may have,or may not. Doesn't matter. My task is to convert UI elements on the fly, so submit data is not related to this question.

Comment: @dfsq no it is not working.'Remove element' not removing the label of radio button ('Old' , 'New'). And page is get refreshed, changes not persisted.

Comment: Page reloads because you use button type submit. Use type=button. It almost works, replace functionality doesn't.

Comment: @dfsq ya I tried, thanks for the button mistake solution, however radio button are not completely removed. Please suggest solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a bit your code to make it clearer and functionnal.

1. I changed `document.getElementsByName` to `document.querySelectorAll` in order to have a *static* [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), otherwise you would have to use a `while` since the collection will reflect changes made when a radio button is removed. You could also remove them later but it would be multiplying `for-loops` for no reason. Moreover `querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]...` focus only on radio buttons, avoiding errors.
2. I got the label text using [`.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) to affect it to the `option` and used [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove useless white space and line breaks.
3. I used [`remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) to remove the radios and labels from the DOM.
4. As a side note, [radio buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) are meant to have a value. You shouldn't rely on the label IMO.

```js
function replaceRadiosBySelect(name) {
  var selectList = document.createElement('select'),
      radios     = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][name="' + name + '"]');
  
  if (radios.length > 0) {
    selectList.name = name;
    radios[0].parentNode.appendChild(selectList);

    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
      var label  = radios[i].nextSibling,
          option = document.createElement('option');

      option.value = option.text = label.data.trim();
      selectList.appendChild(option);

      radios[i].remove();
      label.remove();
    }
  }
}

replaceRadiosBySelect('Type');
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    Car Type
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="radio" name="Type"> Old
    <input type="radio" name="Type"> New
  </td>
</tr>
```